# When turning on the screen automatically appears the Unlock Pin typing field

Tags: lock-screens, 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have an app that performs automatic actions, but for that it needs to unlock my screen.

It doesn't have the Swipe + Pin option.

Pin only.

In version 8.0 of Android (latest for Galaxy S7 Edge) is there a way to make the screen turn on already on the screen where you type the Pin instead of having to do a swipe before it appears?

It is currently swipe then pin, see:

[image]

[image]